# Select only certain data type in Microsoft SQL query

Tags: vba, ms-access, select, sqldatatypes

In Access 2007 I need to select all the short-text fields in a table.

VBA code should look like this:

```
    Dim strClient As String
    Set dbs = CurrentDb()
    Debug.Print Me.ID

    strClient = "Select * from ANG_CLIENTS where DATA_TYPE='TEXT' AND ID=" & Me.ID

    Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strClient)
```

I get "Runtime error 3061. Too few parameters. Expected 1" on the last assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a custom function to loop through the recordset fields and extract the names of text fields only.

The names can then be added to your SQL script.

```
Public Function TextDataFileds(rs As DAO.Recordset) As String

    Dim fld As DAO.Field, item As String

    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        If fld.Type = 10 Then 'dbText
            item = IIf(Len(item) = 0, fld.Name, item & ", " & fld.Name)
        End If
    Next fld

    TextDataFileds = item
End Function
```

You can then call it like this:

```
Sub Test()
    On Error GoTo ErrProc

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ANG_CLIENTS;")

    Dim sql_ As String
    sql_ = "SELECT " & TextDataFileds(rs) & " FROM ANG_CLIENTS WHERE ID=" & Me!ID

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    Set rs = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset(sql_)

    '....

Leave:
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrProc:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```

Comment: @Parfait Thanks, I overlooked this.

Comment: @Parfait: "IIf is not a VBA function" ... Oh, it is. Type `VBA.I` and IntelliSense brings it forward as your first choice.